# Fonts licensing

Tags: typography

I would love a clear and simple rule of thumb about using fonts for a commercial purpose.

Can I use pre installed fonts on my Mac like Arial for body copy. Do you need to buy the font in every instance?

I have a creative cloud subscription so I have read I can use typekit without buying individual licenses but what about if you discontinue the subscription and the font is already being used on a product or website?

Any clarification would be great thank you

Alexis

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to buy a font every time you use it - only once.  When you bought your computer, you also bought the licence to use the fonts which were included in the OS.

What you can't do is redistribute those fonts.  For example, you can't legally give the font files to someone else.

If you discontinue your Adobe Creative Cloud then you lose your connection to your Typekit fonts - since they are not installed locally on your computer (at least not where you will easily find them, but they are there!)

Comment: Plus embedding in websites or mobile apps usually isn't covered with system fonts licenses.

Comment: @AAGD an excellent point.